# how to get values from a const object?

Tags: dart

I created a const object at app.config.dart with the following code:

```
const configObj = const {
 'webServer': const {
   'appBaseHref' : "/"
 },
 'auth0': const {
   'apiKey': "foo",
   'domain': "bar",
   'callbackUrl': "callback"
 }
};
```

now in my main dart file I import the `app.config.dart` and I try to get the values there and now idea how to do that. `configObj.auth0.apiKey` produces the error `EXCEPTION: Class 'ImmutableMap' has no instance getter 'auth0'`.

so how do I do this ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart doesn't support to access map entries with `.`

It should be:

```
configObj['auth0']['apiKey'];
```

Alternatively you can create classes for your configuration like

```
class WebServerConfig {
  final String appBaseHref;
  const WebServerConfig(this.appBaseHref);
}

class Auth0Config {
  final String apiKey;
  final String domain;
  final String callbackUrl;
  const Auth0(this.apiKey, this.domain, this.callbackUrl);
}

class MyConfig {
  final WebServerConfig webServer;
  final Auth0Config auth0;
  const MyConfig(this.webServer, this.auth0);      
}

const configObj = const MyConfig(
  const WebServerConfig("/"),
  const Auth0Config(
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "callback"
  )
);
```

This way you also get proper auto-completion when you access the config properties and can use the simple `.` notation to access properties.